# Multioutput regression with varying target size

Tags: nlp, regression

I wan to solve a math words problem using Machine learning.
as in the following picture:
using the 'text' column, predict the 'ans_simple' column.

[image]

The problem is that the number of variables in the target is not the same in every row.
how can I work with a varying multi target problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting case.

If you find the maximum number of result in ans_simple columns, lets say 5, then you can oversample your results with 0.

For example if you have

> [40,29]

and your maximum number of result is 5, it will be like :

> [40,29,0,0,0]

This is just an heuristic implementation that came into my mind.

Other thing that came to my mind is that; İf you divide your target variable into N number of target variables (MultiOutput Model), it may work well.